# RXJS: Easiest way of implememnt react-query-like caching with observables (stale-while-revalidating)

Tags: rxjs, stream, observable, react-query, tanstackreact-query

The default way of implement caching with observables is this one:

```
import { shareReplay } from "rxjs";
import { fromFetch } from "rxjs/fetch";

const source$ = fromFetch("https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5");
const cached$ = source$.pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

Each time someone subscribes on cached$, it gets cached value and doesn't subscribe to the source. The default behavior of the lib [React-query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest) does the stale-while-revalidating approach and refetch data for each new request using cache only as a placeholder.

Of course, you could use some complicated logic using a Map and many observable operators to simulate this same behavior (I even implemented already implemented this, but it was over-complicated), but the intention of this question is to find a simple and clean way of doing this. How can we do that in RXJS?

Comment: `react-query` is a whole library, but fortunately it now has a core package `@tanstack/query-core` which can help you build upon the same building blocks. It contains lots of logic for delay-based caching, etc. Maybe you'd also want Cache-Control based caching?

Comment: You could also have a look at `@mmuscat/angular-swr`